# Why does my batch file stop after prompting for input?

Tags: batch-file, game-development

I am designing a text game in a batch file. When my code reaches the point where I need to input a number to decide what action to perform, the Command Prompt window simply closes.

```
@echo off
set /a EHP = 10
set /a BaseDamage = 1
set /a SpecialDamage = 2
set /a SpecialCost = 5
set /p input = .
if %input% == 1 or %input% == hit (
 echo you hit the enemy
 set /a EHP = %EHP% - %BaseDamage%
 )
if %input% == 2 or %input% == kick (
 echo you kick the enemy
 set /a EHP = %EHP% - %BaseDamage%
 )
if %input% == 3 or %input% == special hit (
 echo [insert dialoge here]
 set /a EHP = %EHP% - %SpecialDamage%
 set /a SP = %SP% - %SpecialCost%
 )
goto a
```

Comment: You should use set `"EHP=10"` and `"input=."`, this way all your variables have names like `EHP (empty space)`

Comment: Im sorry. Im new to this and not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: added answer with explanation.

Comment: There is no `or` operator in batch scripts, so you need to change your logic accordingly; note that something like `and` can be simulated by `if %a%==1 if %b%==1 (do something)`; you can do the same with the `not` keyword, like `if not %a%==1 if not %b%==1 (do something)` (this constitutes something like `nor`); when using this together with `else`, be careful with `else` belongs to which `if`; you can of course use individual `if` statements to keep it simple; then you can use `goto` and jump to the respective action...

Comment: To debug batch files, do not double-click them, but enter them into a command prompt window, so you can see any error messages thrown; remove `@echo off` to see what is going on, and consider to place `pause` at certain positions where you want to check particular code...